# "Ability of [gerund]" vs. "ability to [infinitive]"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-of

I want to say one of the following:

> - For them, ability of speaking is worthless since all the them are great speakers.
> - For them, ability to speak is worthless since all of them are great speakers.

Which one is more natural to a native speaker?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary? [Here's one](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ability?region=uk&q=ability) which contains an illustrative example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ability **to** speak" is correct:

> For them, **the** ability **to speak** is worthless **because** all of them are great **speakers**.

but the semantics of the sentence, no matter how it's said, is illogical because of the word "**worthless**".

Maybe "**is worthless**" should be "**is unimportant**" or "**is of secondary importance**" or "**isn't {an issue/a problem}**".

Comment: Is 'ability of' is completely wrong? A google search shows some usage of it, although they do not look very credible!

Comment: I think it's completely wrong and that no native speaker would use it. Except, of course, in sentences like "**Assessing the driving ability of the elderly is important in 2012**". But your sentence is not of this type. You can't trust Google to give you only examples of native-speaker English. Everybody in the world uses English, but not everyone writes natural idiomatic native-speaker English.

Comment: Dilawar- When *ability* means *the fact of being able to do something*, it's always followed by an *infinitive*.

Comment: Re _worthless_: _worth_ means the same as _value_ in the sense of _something prized_. It does not mean _value_ in the different sense you mean it here, _a criterion for distinguishing something_.

Comment: @ColinFine: I don't see the distinction you're making: _All of them are great speakers. Therefore, they do not prize the ability to speak._ What's the missing premise here? "_Great speakers don't prize the ability to speak._"?

Comment: @BillFranke: I was replying to the OP, not to you, so I'm reinforcing your point, not disagreeing with it; sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @ColinFine: Oh. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I thought your comment was directed at my answer and disagreeing with it.